# Why does IE9 draw this div incorrectly in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I'm somewhat new to html and css and I am having a really strange issue with this ASP.NET page. The following code draws the div (should be 50x50) as 50x100 in IE9. It may be drawing twice. In Compatibility mode it works just fine. As you can see it's a super-simple piece of code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DivAlignmentTest.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #Div1
        {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: Red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="Div1" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Jason

Comment: Not the best at HTML, but I don't believe that you can close divs like that. They need the </div> tag. At least, I don't think it's part of the HTML standard. And even less so in XHTML.

Comment: Is the default CSS reset? Try a non self closing div.

Comment: Can I say "because it's IE"? Anyway, *make sure the markup is valid first* (e.g. W3C validator). Otherwise, the browser can do whatever in heck it wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<div id="Div1" />
```

to

```
<div id="Div1"></div>
```

should make it work properly.

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast! That was exactly the problem. Much thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cant self close a div tag

Try:

```
<div id="Div1"></div>
```